# How can I guarantee that T is a class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have the next code:

```
public static T GetSerializedCopy<T> (T src)
{
  //some code to obtain a copy
}
```

How I can guarantee that T will be a class, not a struct or enum or simething else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy to ensure that...

```
    public static T GetSerializedCopy<T>(T src) where T : class
    {
        //some code to obtain a copy
        return default(T);
    }
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't ensure that T is a class; it ensures that it is a *reference*

Comment: Not related to the OP's question, but default(T) doesn't give you a copy of T, it gives you a blank new T.

Comment: @VVS no it doesn't - it gives `null` - but I'm pretty sure cyberzed intends that to be read as "TODO : your code here"

Comment: Was just a this can compile and stuff...though I gotta say I like the rep @MarcGravell has the right answer.

Comment: This is the oddest selection for the correct answer.  The code is incorrect (well, the signature is but that `return default(T)` should be removed), it doesn't include any references, wasn't the first answer nor is it the best... Now I'm never going to overtake [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 21):

It is a **common mistake** (see the answers here) to think that adding `where T : class` to the generic method/type declaration achieves this - but this is wrong. This *actually* means "`T` must be a reference type", which includes delegates and interfaces too (plus arrays, and things like `string`).

If you want a class, there are two ways; the easiest is to insist on `where T : class, new()`, since neither an interface nor a delegate can have constructors. This does have false negatives, though, in terms of rejecting classes without public parameterless constructors.

The only other way is at runtime:

```
if(!typeof(T).IsClass) throw new InvalidOperationException("T must be a class");
```

Equally, `where T : struct` doesn't mean "`T` must be a value-type", either! It means "`T`must be a **non-nullable** value-type"; types involving `Nullable<>` do not satisfy `T : struct`, despite the fact that `Nullable<Foo>` **is** a `struct`.

Comment: You should refactor your comments here :-)

Comment: You just had to snatch my low hanging fruit from my greedy fingers and smash it, didn't you?

Comment: clarification: the `.IsClass` check would typically be used **in addition to** a `where T : class` constraint - the latter deals with the majority of obvious failings. You could make this check as granular as needed.

Comment: They could though be making the other common mistake, of thinking they need to ensure `T` is a class when what they really need to do is ensure it's a reference type. There are plenty of cases where you can't do something with a value-type, but you can with a delegate, interface, or boxed value-type.

Comment: @Jon agreed; it all comes down to exactly what the OP means in their question - but it is valuable having answers here to both meanings, since the *next* person who finds the question may have a different intent

Comment: @MarcGravell 100% agreement. There's value in being a pedant when it comes to code. One rarely manages to be more pedantic than the compiler, after all :) My comment is as much to the same goal as anything else.

Comment: @MarcGravell nice explanation. though we also understood wrongly, now got to know some new thing :)

Answer (score 7):

```
public static T GetSerializedCopy<T> (T src) where T : class
```

[This is the link to MSDN for generic type constraints.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Comment: Actually, that doesn't ensure that T is a class; it ensures that it is a *reference*

Comment: @MarcGravell do you really think thats what the question is asking?

Comment: @MarcGravell: `any class, interface, delegate, or array type`, yes.  But that is as atomic as it gets.  You'll have to perform asserts if this doesn't cut it.

Comment: @32bitkid: Depends on how exact OP was being when he said "class" and "something else".

Comment: @Will i get it, I'm a fan of specificity. but based on the question (its comparison to "not a struct or enum or simething") and the fact that the [first google hit](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+How+can+I+guarantee+that+T+is+a+class) for the literal title of this question (appending "c#") returns the msdn documentation of type constraints, i'm still gonna go with a +1 on this answer.

Comment: @32bitkid you're a fan of specificity yet you ignore the 'something else' bit? Interfaces and delegates don't count as something else?

Comment: @32bitkid what if the "or simething" includes delegates and interfaces? Call me crazy, but I'm guessing that when they ask "will be a class", they're expecting that the answer ensures that the type ***is a class***. Just sayin'

Answer (score 2):

you can use Type Constraints, on your interfaces. [Type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

```
where T : class
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't ensure that T is a class; it ensures that it is a *reference*

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
where T: class
```

Yes..

```
public static T GetSerializedCopy<T> (T src)
   where T : class
{
  //some code to obtain a copy
}
```

Comment: Actually, that doesn't ensure that T is a class; it ensures that it is a *reference*

Comment: Yes Marc, but that is the intention of OP here.

Comment: that depends on how we interpret "guarantee that T will be a class, not a struct or enum or simething else" - an `interface` is not a class; a `delegate` is borderline; either would satisfy `T : class`